# git basic setup

Tags: git

I have (finally) convinced my manager to allow us to set up version control, and have been doing some research for the past few days and have decided on git.
Anyways I found a tutorial here 
http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto
on a basic setup, that will push changes to remote repository.
This would work great for our company.

Here are the steps I went through

**Local box**

```
cd /website
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit into git"
```

**server**

```
cd /var/git/
mkdir website.git
cd website.git
git init --bare

mkdir /var/www/website

cat > hooks/post-receive

#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/website git checkout -f
```

chmod +x hooks/post-receive

**Local Box**

```
git remote add web ssh://user@server/var/git/website.git
git push web +master:refs/heads/master
```

Now where i do the push I get the error "This operation must be run in a work tree" This is coming from the post-receive hook.
I know I am missing a step but just not sure what exactly that is...

Comment: I'd try removing the post-receive hook, doing my initial push, and then replacing the post-receive hook.  Maybe the hook doesn't want to run on a repo with no commits at all?

Comment: Did you evaluate https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite ? Later on you might want to organize your branches: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: I don't have time to find a duplicate, but there are probably a dozen of them here. Try searching for similar questions.

Comment: +1 for gitolite. It is a great, great addition to git and handles access control even more finely than what svn or cvs can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your working directory `website` is empty. Hence, your `git add .` does not add anything, and the next commit does not create a new commit.

In order to generate the master branch, you need to complete at least one commit, with at least one file.

In the local box, do

```
touch empty
git add empty
git commit -m "Initial commit into git"
git push web
```